# ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de exportar la propiedad "data" de un component Children a un component Parent?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Pues resulta que estaba haciendo una to-do list típica en Vue para aprender un poco  lo básico de como funciona y empecé a hacerla en Codepen pero pronto decidí hacerla en mi propio pc con vue cli.

En concreto mi problema se trata de una funcionalidad *v-model* de un input y dos *v-if* de un `<h2>` no están funcionado. **Con los mismos datos en mi proyecto de vue cli no me funciona, y en el codepen si.** Creo que es un error de exportar la propiedad data, que es donde se encuentran los mensajes que deben aparecer condicionalmente en los :

```js
// componente "PreTodo.vue"

<template>
    <div>
    // Si el mensaje_af está vacío imprime el mensaje_be, sino está vacio (si se está escribiendo en el input) entonces imprime el mensaje_af + "To-Do Lista":
    <h2 v-if="mensaje_af === ''">{{mensaje_be}}</h2>
    <h2 v-if="mensaje_af !== ''">{{mensaje_af + " To-Do Lista"}}</h2>
    // Este input Escucha e imprime lo que esté en el mensaje_af:
    <input v-model="mensaje_af" type="text" /><button>CREATE</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "PreTodo",
    data: {
        mensaje_be: "Da Nombre a tu To-Do",
        mensaje_af: "",
    }
}
</script>
```

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <section class="hero is-warning is-fullheight">
        <!-- Container del Centro .start-->
        <div class="hero-body">
          <div class="container">
            <PreTodo />
            <Todo />
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Container del Centro .end -->
         <div class="hero-foot">
            <p>Somebody M.A.D.E. this</p>
          </div>
          
      </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PreTodo from './components/PreTodo'
import Todo from "./components/Todo"
// Debo importar aquí la propiedad data del componente PreTodo aquí abajo?:
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
      PreTodo,
      Todo
  }
}
</script>
```

Lo que me aparece en la pantalla es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además por supuesto, una vez que empiezo a escribir en el input no se actualiza el mensaje en el `<h2>` al contrario que en el codepen que si lo hace.

Este es el repo onlien donde si funciona bien: https://codepen.io/Assblack/pen/pozeeXB?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para exportar la `data` en tus componentes usando el cli debes usarla como una función y dentro de ella hacer el `return` de tus propiedades de esta forma:

```
// foo.vue
...
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      mensaje_be: "Da Nombre a tu To-Do",
      mensaje_af: "",
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

y si usas vue en modo standalone podrías usar la misma estructura `data(){return{...}}` o:

```
// foo.js
new Vue({
  data: {
    mensaje_be: "Da Nombre a tu To-Do",
    mensaje_af: "",
  }
})
```